# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I received the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

```
    private void addToOrder(DataRowView drv)
    {
        DataRow dr = orderDataTable.NewRow();
        dr["ProductID"] = drv["ProductID"];
        dr["ProductBarcode"] = drv["ProductBarcode"];
        dr["ProductName"] = drv["ProductName"];
        dr["SalePrice"] = drv["SalePrice"];
        dr["SoldQuantity"] = 1;
        dr["NotEditable"] = false;
        try
        {
            orderDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        catch (ConstraintException)
        {
            DataRow dr1 = orderDataTable.Rows.Find(drv["ProductID"]);
            dr1["SoldQuantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(dr1["SoldQuantity"]) + 1;
        }
    }
    private void btnAddToOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // add to order
        if(txtBarcodeAuto.Text.Length >0)
        {
            //get data from sql server database for product details(productID, ProductName,ProductPrice)
            DataTable dscrntProd = prods.SelCrntProd4Sale(crntProdID);
            foreach (DataRowView dr in dscrntProd.Rows)
            {
                addToOrder(dr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is coming in following line due to data type mismatch.

```
foreach (DataRowView dr in dscrntProd.Rows) // as dscrntProd  is DataTable
```

It should be like

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dscrntProd.Rows)
{
  addToOrder(GetOrderDataRowViewFromDataFow(dr));
}
```

You need to write `GetOrderDataRowViewFromDataRow`.

Comment: Apart from your conclusion, he don't need to write `GetOrderDataRowViewFromDataRow` but change the signature of `addToOrder` to take `DataRows` as @Reacher has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Well, geez, don't do that, then. Try this instead:

```
private void addToOrder(DataRow drv)
{
    ....
}

foreach (DataRow dr in dscrntProd.Rows)
{
    addToOrder(dr);
}
```

Comment: Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this. Doctor: Don't do that, then. (Edited my comment )

Answer (score 0):

DataRowis not convertable to DataRowView

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dscrntProd.Rows)
{
    addToOrder(dr);
}

private void addToOrder(DataRow dr) // change the function argument to DataRow.
    {// Do something.
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: -1 `DataTable.Rows` does return a collection of `DataRows` not `DataRowViews`.

Comment: However, this is the same as @Reachers answer now, so i don't see the added value. You might want to delete it then.

Comment: actually i wanted to write this. but as soon as i post, Reachers posting is done before me. At first i saw there were no answer for this question. Anyways hope Reachers answere helps. thanks.

Comment: when I do that , I got this error:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."